# Setters in UITextField in iOS7 doesn't work but work in iOS6

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

```
    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    ...

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        VVUserInformationCell *cell = (VVUserInformationCell*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
        NSLog(@"%@", array[i][1]);

        [cell.userData setText: array[i][1]];
        [cell.userData setTag:i];
        NSLog(@"%@", cell.userData.text);
        NSLog(@"%d", cell.userData.tag);
    }
}
```

In iOS6 it work very well. But in iOS7 in array[i][1] is what I want but in cell.userData.text after setText is null and after setTag in everything is 0.
cell is part of UITableView which is subview of my controller and userData is UITextField inside cell.

Comment: It might be smart to edit your question to show what your "`VVUserInformationCell`" code looks like.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:...]
```

returns `nil` for rows that are currently not visible (and it may return `nil`
generally in `viewWillAppear:`).
In that case `cell.userData` is `nil`, and setting a text or a tag has no effect at all.

It seems that you are (ab)using
the table view cells as data source. That cannot work, due to the above reason, and
because table view cells are *reused*.

You have to fill the cell contents in the

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the UITableViewDataSource/cellForRowAtIndexPath methods to configure your cell with what's in array[i][1]

Something like this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section; {
    return [array count];
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    VVUserInformationCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"VVUserInformationCellID"];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] @"VVUserInformationCell" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    [cell.userData setText:array[indexPath.row][1]];
    [cell.userData setTag:indexPath.row]

    return cell;
}
```